# WebBrowser control - Need navigation error handling

Tags: c#, browser, windows-ce

I'm writing an app in C# on Windows CE 5.0 with .NET Framework 3.5 that uses the WebBrowser control. It's almost exactly what I need, with the exception that it throws a global exception when it fails to .Navigate(...) as opposed to an exception out of the Navigate call.

I've found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createsink.aspx

While this compiles for a Windows application, there are a few things missing when I try to compile them for WinCE. Those being:

- AxHost
- StandardOleMarshalObject
- Anything that starts with Permission*
- ... and a few more that I can't recall at the moment.

I can go ahead writing the app and deal with global exceptions, but it would be much cleaner if I could handle navigation errors properly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a meaningless comment I'm adding so that I can find this question again. Hopefully someone will be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

which thread is the exception coming from?  if you could find/access that thread, you could theoretically handle it's exceptions.